# describe vba syntax

Tags: vba

As I am converting vba code to vb.net and I am familiar with vb.net so I have simple question her

can you describe the following code:

```
    Forms("frmCodeType")!CodeDescriptions = mobCodeType.fstrCodes(Me.CodeTypeKey)
    Forms("frmCodeType")!DefaultCodeKey.Requery()
```

specially the ! mark

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered a bit in the [Access 2002 VBA Handbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188215.aspx):

> Use the bang operator when you are stepping from a collection to one of its members, in the format collectionname!objectname.